# How to create an alias to run a command and exit in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, alias, exit

Here is my alias.

```
alias myAlias='myScript --option& && exit'
```

I want to run the script `myScript` with option `option` in background and then exit from bash. I want to set it up as an alias called myAlias in my bashrc file. However, I am getting an syntax error when I try to run `myAlias`. How to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: `nohup myScript --option& exit`

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. I tried replacing myScript with gedit and option with encoding and it doesn't work. However if I try removing option altogether, then it works.

Comment: `--option&` looks like typo, is it really legal?

Comment: Well no idea, maybe it is legal, but I am not sure if we can use exit after that. Maybe we need a semicolon or && before exit.

Comment: `gedit` puts itself in background.

Comment: But I don't see a gedit window appear anywhere, when I try this, which brings me back to the same problem again.

Comment: Which is why `gedit` is a bad test case. Is it _possible_ for a program to break when run like this? Absolutely. Is it _typical_ for programs to break when run like this? Nope: most programs would work fine. Since you don't give any details about what your script does, it isn't possible to make a definitive statement about what's going on. _shrug_

Comment: I want my script to be any program installed on my machine like gedit or eclipse etc.

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me:

```
alias myAlias='nohup myScript --option& exit'
```

Why not use exit in myScript if you want to run the script with option "option" in background and then exit from bash, because once the program is run in the background , its terminal independent right ?